# Does ImageReader support Base64ImageDeserializer format in CNTK now?

Tags: cntk

I saw Base64ImageDeserializer.cpp was added into CNTK github. https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/00bcf2cbac79fec3597a1ce0ce8445ebdc823ae3/Source/Readers/ImageReader

So I want to ask when base64 encode image as imagereader input will be supported?

Comment: why don't you ask the programmers?

Answer (score 1):

It will be officially announced (with supporting documentation, etc.) by the second half of January, 2017. Base64 image deserializer code has been merged to master, so you can try it out already, even though some pieces are missing (mostly documentation). For examples, please see tests in there: cntk\Tests\UnitTests\ReaderTests\ImageReaderTests.cpp(the ones with Base64).